# how to launch .exe file(desktop application) in one of my jpanel

Tags: java, swing, embed

how to launch .exe file(desktop application) in one of my  jpanel .so that in left panel my .exe file runs and right panel my application runs.

```
{
    String[] params = new String [1];
    params[0] = "C:\\Program Files\\...... Starter.exe";

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

i have written above code it is launching in my application but not in my jpanel. It is launching separately.

Comment: You can't do that. JPanel is a place where you can put components or draw things, it's not a "virtual screen" that would be used by a native program.

Comment: what do you mean "in my jpanel"?

Comment: i have left jpanel1 and right jpanel2. in jpanel .exe desktop application must launch

Comment: and what do you mean by that? exe's run in the memory of your OS, not in your UI. What do you want to show in that JPanel?

Comment: You will find next to near impossible to embedded external processes into Swing - Swing doesn't paint the same way most applications paint.  All embedded solutions (ie VLC) use a `java.awt.Canvas` as the bases for displaying the content and are bound through a series of native libraries to provide that support

Comment: iam suppose to launch the desktop application in my left panel of a jframe.